# applescript : add clipboard content to list

Tags: applescript, copy-paste

Can I create a list from the clipboard?

Let's say my clipboard is `name email phone and any random number of text

Can the words be separated and added in a list?

Also the item can be either text and numbers, but I guess the best way would be to do a text delimiter by space?

Comment: For a solution, just do `set myList to the words of (the clipboard)` which will yield `{"name", "email", "phone"}` for your supplied example data.

Comment: @CJK, you should make an answer out of your comment so it can get upvoted.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was against etiquette, but ok then 

Comment: @CJK, It' not, and technically answers are supposed to be posted as answer, not comments. I'll post an answer as a comment if I don't have time to write a good answer that's more then a one line comment type answer or if I intend to write an actual answer a bit later etc. Anyway, nice expansion on your comment answer as an answer +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say my clipboard is "name email phone" and any random text and numbers.
> Can the **words** be separated and added in a list?

You don't realise it, but you've answered your own question.

#### TL;DR

Say your clipboard contains the string `"Kevin stackexchange.com 124098"`.  Separate this into a list of words like so:

```
words of (the clipboard) --> {"Kevin", "stackexchange.com", "124098"}
```

You can read more about this builtin AppleScript feature below, where I've given a detailed explanation, including why, sadly, this won't be quite as effective if an email address is involved:

```
words of "Kevin@example.com" --> {"Kevin", "example.com"}
```

So you'll either need to remember to restore the obliterated `"@"` symbol later; or, as you suggested, use `text item delimiters` set to a space character.

#### Detailed Information: `text item delimiters` vs `words`

AppleScript `text` objects are comprised of `word` and `character` *elements* that subdivide one another into the component building blocks of any string: `text` subdivides into `words` and/or `characters`; a `word` subdivides into `characters`.

Moreover, the `words` subdivide `text` at intervals marked by whitespace of any length, which is much more convenient than `text item delimiters`, which will split a string at each individual occurrence of a specified delimiter.

For example, setting `text item delimiters` to the `space` character, and applying it to a two-word phrase with three spaces between them, you'll end up with this:

```
text items of "foo   bar" --> {"foo", "", "", "bar"}
```

However, obtaining instead the `words` that make up the string avoids having to deal with empty-string list items:

```
words of "foo   bar" --> {"foo", "bar"}
```

Moreover, like `text items`, `words` of a `text` object will subdivide the string naturally into a list of individual items.

For completeness, I'll quickly demonstrate how `characters` will decompose a string:

```
characters of "foo"       --> {"f", "o", "o"}
characters of "foo   bar" --> {"f", "o", "o", " ", " ", " ", "b", "a", "r"}
```

A bit of caution is warranted when decomposing a string into `words`, believing it operates identically (or near enough) to a `space` delimiter.  It doesn't.  There are a defined set of characters that are considered "word characters", and a set of characters that are not.  "Word characters" are any character that, when grouped together, are considered word-forming.  If any non-word character appears, the word is considered split into two distinct words at that character.

Word characters basically include the letters A-Z and a-z (and any accented variants), numbers 0-9, the period (`.`) and the underscore (`_`).  So `"tH1s"` is a word, and `"this_is_a_single_word.123"`.  However, `"this#is%four words"`, and, counterintuitively to me, `"over-achieving"` is considered two words (the hyphen is a non-word character).

Other non-word characters obviously include the space; or any whitespace for that matter.  Plus any symbol you can type with your keyboard that wasn't included in the list of word characters, **except** the dollar sign (`$`), which I annoyingly left to now to mention just to reflect how annoying it is that it's randomly considered a word character:

```
words of "hello#$&world" --> {"hello", "$", "world"}
```